# Rolling 12 month Sum DAX - Ignore all date filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've  been working on writing a dax so that I can get the sum sales amount for the last 12 calendar months.  I've played with ALL and KEEPFILTERS but I still can't seem to get it.  Below is an example of what I've tried.  But I don't want just 365 days back.. I would like 12 Calendar Months (or I would settle for going back to the 1st day of 12 calendar months and then ending on today).  IE:  Today it would be 1/1/19 to 2/6/2020
'''

```
var varToday =  Today()
var varYearAgo = varToday - 365
RETURN


CALCULATE(
    SUM(FACT[Earnings]),
    FILTER('Earnings',
 'Earnings'[PayDate] <= varToday
 && 'Earnings'[PayDate]>= varYearAgo
))
```

'''

Below is howt he data looks

[image]

I have added a calendar table as well:  DimCalendar and attempted this as my DAX

'''

```
var varEarnings = SUM(Fact[Earnings])



RETURN 


CALCULATE (
   varEarnings ,
    ALLEXCEPT ( DIMCalendar, DIMCalendar[Date] ),
    DATESINPERIOD( DIMCalendar[Date], today(), -12, MONTH )
)
```

'''

Comment: You should add a Calendar table to you data model, and then use time intelligence functions like DATESINPERIOD or DATESBETWEEN.

Comment: ALLEXCEPT could used here to ignore filter context. if you have an data example that would help

Comment: I added a pic of how the data looks for this part.

Answer (score 0):

To get the date filter you are looking for, you can simply using the edate function to subtract months from the date:

```
Rolling Sum = 
VAR varToday = TODAY()
VAR varYearAgo = DATE(YEAR(EDATE(End1,-13)),MONTH(EDATE(End1,-13)),1)
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(FACT[Earnings]),
    FILTER('Earnings','Earnings'[PayDate] <= varToday),
    FILTER('Earnings','Earnings'[PayDate] >= varYearAgo),
))
```

To remove the filters applied you would have to use ALL() or ALLEXCEPT() or ALLSELECTED() in your calculation. The usage will vary depending on the specific context. Hope this helps.